# Multi threadings in PHP

Tags: php

I have configure threads in php as per this link http://docs.php.net/manual/en/pthreads.installation.php#115004 but while executing the code the error remains there as Class 'Thread' not found.
For the installation and configuring I have placed dll files to their locations and have enabled extentions and php threads safety has also been enabled..
Kindly help me with this..

I think its not finding the thread class, if I have to manually create it, where it should be placed then..??

Comment: Go sure you use the correct version. it has to be compatible with your php version :)

Comment: I have checked it again and again :(